# MPI Reduce with mpi_datatype

Tags: c++, mpi, custom-data-type

How can reduce to first K results of a specify MPI_Type that is a struct of pointers to matrices/vectors with different sizes? I know that I can't pass address between process but I really need pass or specify size of matrices when reduce or only copy the data in operation?

My struct is:

```
//vector/vector of vector can be translated by static vector
struct reg{
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > A; //have exactly NxN
    RegTD *TD; //have exactly 1 << N
    int N;
    std::vector<int> Basin; //max 1<<N
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > BasinInfo; //max Bsize.size() * Bsize.size()
    float Entropy;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Boost::MPI.   Boost will serialize and deserialize types for you.  It might not be exactly what you want.  The other approach Boost takes is described here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.skeleton_and_content  where you send a "skeleton" describing the structure an then the "content" describing the actual data.